# Python Regex to extract multiple complex groups

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract some groups of data from a text and validate if the input text is correct. In the simplified form my input text looks like this:

```
Sample=A,B;C,D;E,F;G,H;I&other_text
```

In which A-I are groups I am interested in extracting them.

In the generic form, Sample looks like this:

```
val11,val12;val21,val22;...;valn1,valn2;final_val
```

arbitrary number of comma separated pairs which are separated by semicolon, and one single value at the very end.
There must be at least two pairs before the final value.

The regular expression I came up with is something like this:

```
r'Sample=(\w),(\w);(\w),(\w);((\w),(\w);)*(\w)'
```

Assuming my desired groups are simply words (in reality they are more complex but this is out of the scope of the question).
It actually captures the whole text but fails to group the values correctly.

Comment: In the `Sample` you showed us, `&` appears to be a terminating marker character.  Would that always be the case?  Your generic sample does not seem to imply this.

Comment: It's not always the case, it can appear or not. That's why I did not provide it in the generic form.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Are you looking for a regex that can magically know how many 2-pair values are in your input text? You already have to parse the string to figure that out.

Comment: Or are you looking for a specific regex that can be used to get each pair individually and then the final value?

Comment: I am looking for a regex that can find 2 or more value pairs plus a single value in a given text. I am not sure if regex is capable of doing that, that's my question. The answer can simply be, "you cannot do that with regex".

Answer (score 0):

I am just assuming that your "values" are any composed of any characters other than `,` and `;`, i.e. `[^,;]+`. This clearly needs to be modified in the `re.match` and `re.finditer` calls to meet your actual requirements.

```
import re

s = 'Sample=val11,val12;val21,val22;val31,val32;valn1,valn2;final_val'

# verify if there is a match:
m = re.match(r'^Sample=([^,;]+),+([^,;]+)(;([^,;]+),+([^,;]+))+;([^,;]+)$', s)
if m:
    final_val = m.group(6)
    other_vals = [(m.group(1), m.group(2)) for m in re.finditer(r'([^,;]+),+([^,;]+)', s[7:])]
    print(final_val)
    print(other_vals)
```

Prints:

```
final_val
[('val11', 'val12'), ('val21', 'val22'), ('val31', 'val32'), ('valn1', 'valn2')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regex that has an OR in it to decide which kind of data you are parsing. I spaced out the regex for commenting and clarity.

```
data = 'val11,val12;val21,val22;valn1,valn2;final_val'

pat = re.compile(r'''
    (?P<pair>  # either comma separated ending in semicolon
        (?P<entry_1>[^,;]+)  ,  (?P<entry_2>[^,;]+)  ;
    )
    | # OR
    (?P<end_part>  # the ending token which contains no comma or semicolon
        [^;,]+
    )''', re.VERBOSE)

results = []
for match in pat.finditer(data):
    if match.group('pair'):
        results.append(match.group('entry_1', 'entry_2'))
    elif match.group('end_part'):
        results.append(match.group('end_part'))

print(results)
```

This results in:

```
[('val11', 'val12'), ('val21', 'val22'), ('valn1', 'valn2'), 'final_val']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this without using regex, by using string.split.

An example:

```
words = map(lambda x : x.split(','), 'val11,val12;val21,val22;valn1,valn2;final_val'.split(';'))
```

This will result in the following list:

```
[
 ['val11', 'val12'],
 ['val21', 'val22'],
 ['valn1', 'valn2'],
 ['final_val']
]
```

Comment: I know there are so many other ways to solve this problem, for example with text parsing and splitting. My question is how to solve it with regular expression, if possible